# Uneven columns' height!

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column

I'm new to LaTeX and, although I find the program quite interesting, it is difficult to get things right immediately. This time I need to do something simple, but I haven't managed to find a solution.

[image: page001]

As you can see, my columns are perfectly aligned on the first page. The problem appears on the second page of thee document. Do you see it? There is a gap at the bottom, near the pagination! Same issue on third one. I want them to be even.

[image: page002]

Any ideas how to solve this conundrum?

This is what I have:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\flushbottom}
% sets twocolumn environment
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\bibliographystyle{nature}      
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}                      
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{bbm}        
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[]{subfigure}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{url}
% Define a new 'leo' style for the package that will use a smaller font.
\makeatletter
\def\url@leostyle{
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sffamily}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{leo}


\begin{document}
% starts supressing the twoculomn environment, from here on it will we one column
\twocolumn[\begin{@twocolumnfalse}

% make a section
\section*{\huge{Contemporary Phantasms}}
\vspace{5mm}    
\normalsize

Author: Antonio Palacios\newline 

\vspace{5mm}
% the * in \section*{Abstract:} makes that this section will not be listed if you do a \tableofcontents.
\section*{Abstract} 

Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris. 

\vspace{8mm}

%begins tabular
\begin{tabular}{p{1,5cm}p{12,55cm}p{1,5cm}}   

% to center the Keywords i did a table with 3 columns and used the first and the last one as free space

&\textbf{Keywords}: Barad $\cdot$ Baudrillard $\cdot$ Bridle $\cdot$ existence $\cdot$ hyperreality $\cdot$ New Aesthetic $\cdot$quantum field theory $\cdot$ render ghosts $\cdot$ simulacrum $\cdot$ virtual $\cdot$ void & \\

\end{tabular} 
% ends tabular


\vspace{11mm}

\end{@twocolumnfalse}]  % ends suppressing the twocolumn environment, from here on it will be twocolumn

\section*{Introduction}% make section 
At the end of the last millennia, "The Truman Show" film \cite{truman} starred by Canadian born comedian Jim Carrey was received with great acclaim. The movie depicted a nonchalant man who lived all his life unaware that he was only a character inside a televised program. It was only by an accumulation of signs that he ended up uncovering the truth.
\newline  \newline  
In "The Truman Show," the scope of reality television was cleverly questioned: What if we were only props in a simulated world? I cannot but wonder that Truman Burbank is the perfect analogy for a virtual entity. Isolated in a parallel space, living in an idyllic world, raised as real but fake as a forgery bill. \newline  \newline  
In the present era, reality TV shows are not shocking anymore. In the same manner, the fact that our environment has been systematically been duplicated does not surprises us. On a daily basis, we experience a series of simulated phenomena and we do not even bother to question what is substantial, and what is not. In fact, it would be almost impossible to distinguish, because that is by definition a property of simulacrum. In spite of that difficulty, on the following sections I will be revising theories and views of bright spirits that have decided to question aspects such as simulation, ontology, and virtuality.


\section*{Hyperreal beings} % make section 
Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris. 
\newline  \newline  
Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris. 
\newline  \newline  
Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris. 
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{Today abstraction is no longer that of the map, the double, the mirror, or the concept. Simulation is no longer that of a territory, a referential being, or a substance. It is the generation by models of a real without origin or reality: a hyperreal}.”  \cite[p.~1]{baudrillard}
\newline  \newline  
Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris, 
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris. }.” \cite[p.~1]{baudrillard}
\newline  \newline  
Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris.  
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{It is no longer a question of imitation, nor duplication, nor even parody. It is a question of substituting the signs of the real for the real, that is to say of an operation of deterring every real process via its operational double, a programmatic, metastable, perfectly descriptive machine that offers all the signs of the real and short-circuits all its vicissitudes}.” \cite[p.~2]{baudrillard}
\newline  \newline  
Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris. 
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{The closer one gets to the perfection of the simulacrum (…), the more evident it becomes (…) how everything escapes representation, escapes its own double and its resemblance}.”\cite[p.~71]{baudrillard}
\newline  \newline  
Aliquam in eleifend sem. Sed nulla massa, pretium non est et, egestas euismod enim. Nulla sed consequat leo. Nullam ultrices metus vitae dolor convallis eleifend. Ut vitae leo laoreet, sodales nisi sit amet, fermentum lacus. Etiam ullamcorper justo et bibendum fringilla. Nunc adipiscing sem non volutpat sagittis. Curabitur at est egestas, tincidunt nunc ac, pretium dolor. Cras et justo eu purus eleifend mollis vel dapibus diam. Nam vitae mi sit amet massa bibendum viverra vel eu justo. Mauris gravida gravida rutrum. Phasellus nec justo interdum, egestas est non, lacinia mauris. 
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{If, according to Mach, the universe is that of which there is no double, no equivalent in the mirror, then with the hologram we are already virtually in another universe: which is nothing but the mirrored equivalent of this one. But which universe is this one}?” \cite[p.~71]{baudrillard}
\newline  \newline  
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 

\section*{A (still) inexistent existence}
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 
\newline  \newline  
I will like to start with a quote from “The Measurement of Nothingness,” which will open a door to further discussion into the matter of existence:
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{Virtuality is not a speedy return, a popping into and out of existence with great rapidity, but rather the indeterminacy of being/non-being, a ghostly non/existence}.” \cite[p.~12]{barad}
\newline  \newline  
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 
\newline  \newline  
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 
\newline  \newline  
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{Virtual particles are short-lived particles that cannot be directly detected, but that affect physical quantities—such as the mass of a particle or the electric force between two charged particles—in measurable ways}.”\cite[p.~38]{dukes}
\newline  \newline  
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 
\newline  \newline  
“\textit{Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. }.” \cite[p.~15]{barad}
\newline  \newline  
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 


\section*{Ghosts}
Vivamus fringilla elit quis enim accumsan tempus. Proin sodales est sed tempus scelerisque. Maecenas molestie urna non tincidunt semper. Integer hendrerit, turpis sed tincidunt auctor, leo augue vehicula est, quis rhoncus sem neque a libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque porttitor eros sed feugiat varius. Vestibulum dictum vulputate malesuada. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a `\raggedbottom` hidden somewhere? What content follows in the second column after your short-broken column?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Thanks @Werner, concerning your question, I have a complete paragraph that has been split automatically by LaTeX:

"This hyper-thirst for the ultimate gadget and a hubristic desire to achieve (a better) reality has leaded us towards a maze of artifices. And then, Elvis appeared from thin air in 2007, materialized thanks(...)"

What is \raggedbottom?

Comment: @killthepixelnow: `\raggedbottom` causes TeX to not worry about aligning the bottom between columns (or pages). If it's issued somewhere in your document, the result could be as you display. Issue `\AtBeginDocument{\flushbottom}` in the preamble.

Comment: I tried \AtBeginDocument{\flushbottom} without success. I don't think it's something related to \raggedbottom. Any other idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: By the way, this is what I have at the beginning:
    \AtBeginDocument{\flushbottom}
    % sets twocolumn environment
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
    \bibliographystyle{nature}    
    \setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: Please (always) include a _complete_ small document that demonstrates the issue, and allows people to test possible answers. A fragment as currently posted is far less useful and makes it less likely that you get an answer.

Comment: what is this? `% starts supressing the twoculomn environment, from here on it will we one column
\twocolumn[\begin{@twocolumnfalse}`  where is the matching `]` to end the optional argument to `\twocolumn` ?

Comment: What @DavidCarlisle said and also what @DavidCarlisle said but, unrelated, there is no point in loading `babel` twice with contradictory options.`\sf` is deprecated. Use `\sffamily` instead. When I make your code compilable, by the way, the base of the columns are perfectly aligned. I assumed you meant something like `\twocolumn[\section*{Contemporary Phantasms}]` to get a heading spanning the two columns but obviously this could be an erroneous assumption.

Comment: I just updated my post with a complete small document. Maybe I am not explaining myself well. I want both the top and the bottom of each column to be perfectly even. As you can see on the attachments, left column has left a small gap at the end, whereas the second column ends after. Call me obsessive, but that drives me nuts!

Comment: @killthepixelnow: Your example only partially fills the first column on the first page. You need to pad it with content so we can replicate your mis-aligned column content...

Comment: @Werner Sorry, I just updated the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll notice that the problem only shows itself for columns where you *only* use paragraph text. Those that have a section heading in them seem to be flush with the bottom...

...this is because you're not using LaTeX's `\parskip` rubber length properly. Forcing a empty line between paragraphs using `\newline\newline` technically still sets the two pieces of text as a single paragraph, and there's currently no way to stretch the lines vertically so that they fit perfectly within the text block given the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) dimensions you use.

The solution here is to add

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\the\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

to your document preamble. The first sets the paragraph break to be the equivalent of an empty line (plus 2pt or maybe minus 1pt, to allow for some flexibility; this may require tweaking). The second removes the paragraph indent (since it seems to be what you're after).

Finally, remove all the `\newline\newline` constructions in your text and use a empty line:

```
The first question will be: What is a simulation and how it differs from a mere 
representation? While both terms can be easily confused, Baudrillard makes an effort to 
differentiate both concepts. When we face an image---a form of representation---we can 
distinguish it from the original. Therefore, reality has not been compromised; in this 
case, it is clear the boundary between the copy and the clone. A simulacrum, on the 
contrary, threatens reality masking it. It no longer resembles reality, because it is a 
product without a basis on reality that fools us.

I like the example of the Borges’ fable given on the first chapter of “Simulacra and 
Simulation,” the book I will be using as a reference in this section \cite{baudrillard}. 
Although the territory existed first, and was used as a matrix to create an ambitious 
exact replica of it, it was the map that survived, masking what it had below. Citizens 
will no more inhabit the real world, but the map. Here and there we can find vestiges 
of the territory, a subverted scenario where reality has been effaced.
```

Comment: Killer solution! Thanks a lot for your help, my document looks neat and tidy, just as I wanted.